# how to strip local namespace from child element

Tags: xml, xslt

I have this XSL that works well for stripping out attributes from elements to produce a final xml document.  however, some of the elements contain local namespaces and Id like to remove those as well.  Here is my current XSL

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

the XML might look something like this

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document>
       <node1>
            <node2 xmlns="www.xml.com">
                   <object>cars</object>
                   <object>boat</object>
            </node2>
       </node1>
</document>
```

I would like the final document to not include xmlns="www.xml.com"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `local-name()` function to get the current node's name.

Using that, instead of copying the existing element (and thus its namespace) you can create a new element and give that element the original element's name.

You'll also need to amend the match statement to ensure that you only capture actual elements; i.e. things such as text nodes still count as nodes, but won't have a local name; so using `element()` instead of `node()` ensures you only capture (named) elements.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="element()">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XSLT Fiddle: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPqsHT3